# R RMarkDown knit_expand encoding

Tags: r, encoding, knitr, r-markdown

In file `main.rmd` have the follownig code:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
out = NULL
for (i in vector) {
  out = c(out, knit_expand("file2.rmd"))
}
```

`r paste(knit(text = out), collapse = '\n')`
````

Both files are saved using UTF-8. However, local signs from `file2.rmd` are not displayed correctly, whereas content from `main.rmd` is displayed without any problem. Adding `encoding="UTF-8"` to `knit` function does not solve the problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may change

```
knit_expand("file2.rmd")
```

to

```
knit_expand(text = readLines("file2.rmd", encoding = "UTF-8"))
```